# Swarm: Create Review without Changes

Tags: perforce, swarm

Is there a way to create a review in Swarm to files without changing them?

**My Use Case:**
I was asked to review an **exist module** in the project. I want to make an online review using Swarm and add comments.

**Update**
From Swarm Documentation:
[Post-commit model](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/swarm/code_reviews.model.html#code_reviews.model.postcommit)
*The post-commit model can be used if your team's development processes preclude the use of shelving. Code must be committed to the Perforce service before code review can begin, which reduces the opportunity to fix problems before, for example, a continuous integration system notices problems. However, code reviews can be started for any existing code regardless of how long it has been committed.*

I think that documentation is talking about having the CL committed first and later review it. I'm talking about an exist code that was developed over period of time and with multiple CLs that need a complete review.

Comment: The documentation says that post-commit reviews are possible, but I haven't found how to do so yet. Also I think your review would have to be at a particular changelist, which might make your exact use case a little trickier.